# How to vertically align multiple equations with text underset?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

How do you vertically align equality signs when one of them has some text
underset? My solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a &\underset{\text{explanation}}{=} b + c\\
  d &\underset{\phantom{\text{explanation}}}{=} e + f + d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

However, that's not very elegant especially when several `\underset` are involved.

Comment: Are you actually referring to horizontal alignment?

Answer (score 3):

The result is not particularly pleasing. If you don't need equation numbers, then an `array` can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a &\underset{\text{explanation}}{=} b + c\\
  d &\underset{\phantom{\text{explanation}}}{=} e + f + d
\end{align*}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r >{{}}c<{{}} l}
  a &\underset{\text{explanation}}{=} & b + c\\
  d &= & e + f + d
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Top your code, bottom mine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Equation numbers would be nice to have. But I see, it's not trivial. I just tried to work with `alignat` but couldn't find a solution. Another solution is to use `\mathclap` around the text, but then of course the word extends over the left- and right-hand side -- which is ugly, too.

Comment: @MariusHofert I really would try a different way; usually the explanation is set to the side of the formula.

Comment: What if you have several equations in a line (because they are short and you don't want to waste space -- as on slides, for example), but you want to address a specific equation? (the problem came up like this on the slides I use to teach). But thanks, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I use `\stackrel` to put text above arrows and stuff. I confess that I'm not sure, but I think it's part of the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Try

```
$\stackrel{-\frac{1}{6} R_3}{\longrightarrow}$
```

Maybe this helps.

Comment: does it or not? what a strange answer!

Comment: it does not. it's apparently a known issue of align that it can't handle relation symbols of different sizes.
note also that your suggestion writes something over the arrow instead of under.